# getElementById selected can't select more than one option

Tags: javascript, html, select, getelementbyid

I have a function in javascript that should allow me to select more than one option, but it only selects the first one.

Javascript:

```
 function index(){
        var a="${staffindex}".replace("[","");
        var b=a.replace("]","");
        var index1=b.split(",");
        for(var i=0;i<index1.length;i++)
            document.getElementById("Staff")[index1[i]].selected=true;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="Staff" name=staff>
                <option value = "1" >option1</option>
        <option value = "2" >option2</option>
        <option value = "3" >option3</option>
        <option value = "4" >option4</option>
        <option value = "5" >option5</option>
</select>
```

index1 is an array of numbers received from a java class.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to use `options` array:

```
document.getElementById("Staff").options[index1[i]].selected=true;
```

Comment: its still gave me one selected

Comment: @user2464576 can you show us please how index1 array looks like?

Comment: the array is just an array of numbers.  ${staffindex} was a string such as [1,2,3].  and index1 is the array.  for instance index1[2] should return 3.

Comment: Works well for me http://jsfiddle.net/cgj2J/ . Are you sure you parse array in correct way?

Comment: I see.  Well, it seems to make sense but it still doesn't work out for some reason.

Comment: My code not work or yours? Check how your array parsed + make sure values are integers. For example: `...ff").options[parseInt(index1[i], 10)].sel...`

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` function in javascript selects only one element. Here it only selects the `<select>` tag since it has the id as `Staff` and not its options. You can however access its options as

```
getElementById("Staff").options[option_number];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function index(){
    var a="${staffindex}".replace("[","");
    var b=a.replace("]","");
    var index1=b.split(",");
    for(var i=0;i<index1.length;i++)
        document.getElementById("Staff").options[index1[i]].selected=true;
}
```

That `options` is very neccessary here!